# How to pass the contents of a file using `cat` to `_values` (zsh completion)

Tags: bash, zsh, zsh-completion

Is it possible to pass the contents of a file using `cat` to `_values` (zsh completion)?

If I uncomment the line `_values cat .test_tasks~` and comment `_values` below, it doesn't work, I get: `_values:compvalues:10: invalid value definition: 1test[1`.

```bsh
#compdef test
#autoload

local curcontext="$curcontext" state line ret=1
local -a _configs

_arguments -C \
  '1: :->cmds' \
  '2:: :->args' && ret=0

_test_tasks() {
  # _values "test" $(cat .test_tasks~)

  _values "test" \
      "1test[1 test test]" \
      "2test[2 test test]"
}

case $state in
  cmds)
        _test_tasks
    ret=0
    ;;
  args)
        _test_tasks
    ret=0
    ;;
esac

return ret
```

#### .test_tasks~

> 1test[1 test test]
>   2test[2 test test]

It seems to be a problem with whitespaces. If I remove the whitespaces:

> 1test[1testtest]
>   2test[2testtest]

it works.

Any ideas?

### Solution:

```bsh
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
_values $(< .cap_tasks~)
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

Reference: [Bash cat command space issue explained](http://www.unixcl.com/2009/12/bash-cat-command-space-issue-explained.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mapfile` module:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
_values ${(f)mapfile[.test_tasks~]}
```

The `mapfile` associative array provides access to the contents of external files. The parameter expansion flag `(f)` splits the resulting expansion on newlines, so that each line of the file will form a separate argument to `_values`.

Comment: Awesome! It worked, thanks. What do you think about the Solution in the answer? I'm just wondering if load a module can be expensive for the completion code.

Comment: A module isn't a shell script; it's just '.so' file linked at runtime, so it should be fast enough. You can also move the `zmodload` command to the top of the file; it doesn't need to be in the function where `mapfile` is actually used.